# How do I get index match to pull correct data

Tags: excel, indexing, match

index match pull data from wrong data

Cell C16 has the following formula "=IF(D16=0,"",INDEX(C1:F1,MATCH(D16,C$16:F$16)))"
is suppose to pull Becky, but it pull Jodi.

When I change some of the other scores, I get different results but never the correct result, unless Susie has the highest score.

Cell D16 has the following formula "=MAX(C15:F15)"

Comment: Add `,0` as the 3rd paramater of `MATCH`.

Comment: Or if an exact match is not possible the range must be sorted in ascending order.

Comment: BigBen: If i put a ,0 I get an error message of "circular references". If I click "OK" it prints to zero.

Comment: C16 is looking at itself as it is in the range in the match statement C$16:F$16. So I suggest you show us the data you want to work with, as what you have gives you the correct result ie circular reference.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was looking at the problem for over an hour and did not see it.

Comment: this is a dummy question from a first time user. How do I upvote an answer to my question?